# How to make the tab key behave like pressing enter on a form ..

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

How can i make my php page so when a user hits TAB or Enter the form submits as if they had pressed enter ?

I can see many snipets trying to make "enter" act like "tab" .. but damned if i can make them work in reverse .. i wan't tab to be like pressing enter on a form..

*why on earth do i want to do this ??*

**Background:** I have a utility type site, its for CSR's to create ftp user accounts and some other stuff on a server, I wrote a while ago in PHP, it has data entry type pages that take each field as you enter them, validates them by submitting the form and then moves to the next field. at the end of the page you hit one final submit and it creates the record.

It's been like this for about 10 years and 99 out of 100 CSR's you just tell them to press enter after filling in each field on the form and the world is happy. However if you press TAB then you lose what you just entered in that field of the form.

I have a new boss who wants these forms to function when you press tab .. hard to tell your boss, just press enter..

Now I know this is not the normal way people write forms, IMHO to validate each field as you enter it is way better then doing all the validation at the end but this seems to be the way the world has decided to go.

anyway before I start re writing this thing from scratch .. there are a dozen of these pages that require a user to press enter not tab .. I thought I would see if i can get my style of form with tab for submission ..

Thanks in advance for any help ..

Bob

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery.... Assuming you have a form like so:

**HTML FORM**

```
        <form enctype="text/plain" method="POST" id="base_form" action="test_this.php">
            <label for="name">Name</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" /><br />
        </form>
```

Then Your JQuery Could look something like this:

**JAVASCRIPT: JQUERY**

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            ;
            jQuery.noConflict();
            (function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function(e) {
                    // CREATE VARIABLE TO HOLD THE FORM OBJECT
                    var baseForm    = $("#base_form");

                    // LISTEN TO A KEYDOWN EVENT RATHER 
                    baseForm.on("keydown", "#name", function(evt){
                        // GET THE KEY THAT WAS PRESSED
                        var charCode    = evt.keyCode || e.which;   

                        // YOU MAY LOG THE RESULT TO THE CONSOLE TO CONFIRM...
                        console.log(charCode);

                        // IF THE KEY IS THE ENTER(13) OR TAB(9) KEY
                        // SIMPLY SUBMIT THE FORM....
                        if(charCode == 9 || charCode == 13){
                            evt.preventDefault();
                            // SUBMIT THE FORM....
                            // alert("SUBMITTING FORM!");  //<== VERY ANNOYING: SO REMOVE IT
                            baseForm.submit();  
                        }
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);

        </script>
```

**TEST: FIDDLE WITH IT AT JS FIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/a96ewgm2/

Comment: Thank you .. this is so close i can taste it ..
 
your sample code for the form works great but my form is more like this ..

`
<?php
 if (isset ($_POST['name'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
 }
  echo 'DEBUG: Value for Name : '.$name.'</br>';
  ?>
<form name="base_form" action="test_this.php" id="base_form"  method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/>
</form>  `

if you out that as the form you will see if you enter a value and press enter the page resubmits and the variable is populated .. 

if you press tab .. no go ..

Comment: @BobDavis  The code has been updated.... you can check again... you may also want to test it at https://jsfiddle.net/a96ewgm2/

Comment: thanks for that .. but still wont work for me .. it give me the dialogue to say it's submitting now but the value is not getting passed back into the form .. :( i am over it for today .. will have another look tomorrow ..